# Argument regarding generators of S3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In my notes, a certain argument goes: Let $H=<(1,2)>$, $K=<(2,3)>$, by the formula $|HK|=2.2/1=4$, we know that $HK$ is not a subgroup of $S_3$ by Lagrange's Theorem.
So far I can follow the argument.

The notes then claim that $S_3=<(1,2),(2,3)>$. May I know how to conclude that? It is probably very trivial but I can't seem to get it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagrange again. The group $U := \left<(1,2),(2,3)\right>$ contains $H$ and $K$ and hence $HK$, so it has at least $4$ elements. But $|U| \mid 6$ and $|U| \ge 4$ implies $|U| = 6$. So $U = S_3$.

Comment: Ah... I see. Thanks